# XAML MVVM binding appears to have succeeded yet is bound to some other variable

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have been writing a project in mvvm where I bind a variable to xaml to show it.
The variable is constantly changed in a thread of the model in a for loop.
Yet, for some reason the gui doesn't change in value.
I have added an if where I check if the value is 62 to see if the value even changes and when I put a break point there the program breaks meaning the problem appears to be in the binding itself.
XAML code:

```
<Label Grid.Row="3" Content="{Binding VM_CurrentTime, Mode = TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1" Margin="-441,7,429,-7"/>
```

The cs behind it:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    vm = new ViewModel(new Model());
    DataContext = vm;
}
```

now as for the vm:

```
public int VM_CurrentTime
    {
        get { return _model.PLine; }
        set
        { // here I added an if (currentValue == 62) to check if current value even changes and it does.
            if (currentTime != value)
            {
                _model.PLine = value;
                currentTime = value;
            }
        }
    }
public void updateData(object notifier, string property)
    {
        switch (property)
        {
            case "line":
                VM_CurrentTime = ((Model)notifier).PLine;
                break;
         }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for the bound objects and fire the event in the setter of all properties

Comment: And remove `Mode=TwoWay` from the Binding. It is useless.